# Blow Up of a Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, birational-geometry

I have a question a step in the example demonstating the blowing up  in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves"  in the excerpt below (or look up at page 320):

[image]

We blow up the surface $X= Spec k[S,T,W]/(ST-W^2)= Spec k[s,t,w)$ in the point $x_0$ corresponding to max ideal $m=(s,t,w)$.

The point of my interest is the fiber $E:=\pi^{-1}(x_)$

I don't understand why the observation that

$$E \cap A_1= V(s)=Spec k[ws^{-1}]$$
$$E \cap A_2= V(t)=Spec k[wt^{-1}]$$
$$E \cap A_3= V(w)=Spec k[tw^{-1},sw^{-1}]/((sw^{-1}) \cdot (tw^{-1})-1)$$

leads to conclusion that $E= \mathbb{P}^1_k$?

Indeed, by definition $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ glues together as $Spec k[x/y] \cup Spec k[y/x]$ on the intersection via $k[x/y,y/x] \to k[x/y,y/x]$

by $ x/y \mapsto y/x$.

Why the calculation in the excerpt imply that $E= \mathbb{P}^1_k$ hold?

Comment: Because he's realized $E$ as the cofibered product of $\mathbb{A}^1$ with itself along $\mathbb{G}_m$ where the gluing map is inversion. This cofibered product is just $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: I'm not sure if I understood you completely so please correct me if I wrong. Since it's not allowed to draw diagrams in comments I outsourced it as an answer:

Answer (score 1):

your cofibered product along $\mathbb{G}_m$ seems to be

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Spec( k[tw^{-1},sw^{-1}]/((sw^{-1}) \cdot (tw^{-1})-1)) @>{g}  >> Spec( k[ws^{-1}]) \\
@VVfV  @VVV  \\
Spec( k[wt^{-1}]) @>{}>> Spec (k[ws^{-1}]) \coprod  Spec( k[wt^{-1}])
\end{CD}
$$

where we identified $E \cap A_1$ and $E \cap A_2$ with $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $E \cap A_3$ with $\mathbb{G}_m$.

Futhermore $g$ is induced by ring map $k[ws^{-1}] \to k[tw^{-1},sw^{-1}]/((sw^{-1}) \cdot (tw^{-1})-1), ws^{-1} \mapsto tw^{-1}$ and

$f$ by $k[wt^{-1}] \to k[tw^{-1},sw^{-1}]/((sw^{-1}) \cdot (tw^{-1})-1), wt^{-1} \mapsto sw^{-1}$

Is this the construction which you mean?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.